# Is there a way to force overlap of two circles?

Tags: matplotlib-venn

I would like to draw a Venn Diagram really close to what the R Limma Package does.

In this case I have a set that does not overlap the two others.
R package shows that with "0", but matplolib-venn draws another circle.

edit:

My 3 sets are:

- 9
- 7 8 9 10
- 1 2 3 4 5 6

My code is:

```
set2 = set([9])
set1 = set([7, 8, 9, 10])
set3 = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

sets = [set1, set2, set3]
lengths = [len(one_set) for one_set in sets]

venn3([set1, set2, set3], ["Group (Total {})".format(length) for (length) in lengths])
```

Thank you.

R Limma: https://i.ibb.co/h9yhgm1/2019-05-07-Screen-Hunter-06.jpg

matplotlib_venn: https://i.ibb.co/zx6YJbz/2019-05-07-Screen-Hunter-07.jpg

Fred

Comment: Hi FredBGA. From your question, it is hard to know what is going on (perhaps you want to have at look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you can send the data you used to create the diagrams, it will be much easier. My guess is that the element in the group with only one element is also in the group with four elements. Both diagrams support this, and both are equivalent.

Comment: Hello, I've edited the question with code and example of sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no element that is common to `set3` and either `set1` or `set2`. Both diagrams are correct. If you want to show all the spaces, you can try with `venn3_unweighted`:

```
from matplotlib_venn import venn3_unweighted

set2 = set([9])
set1 = set([7, 8, 9, 10])
set3 = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

sets = [set1, set2, set3]
lengths = [len(one_set) for one_set in sets]

venn3_unweighted([set1, set2, set3], ["Group (Total {})".format(length) for (length) in lengths])
```

And the result:
[image]

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted to achieve.