# How to increase the patch size of intersection area in matplotlib-venn2 figure?

Tags: python, data-visualization, matplotlib-venn

I have a lot of string values in 2 dataframes and I want to represent the common values in the venn2 intersection.

But the intersection size is coming up really small and text is going beyond the figure size. Like this:

[image]

It would be better if the intersection size is big enough.
Any help would be useful. Thanks.

Comment: May be this can help [Is there a way to force overlap of two circles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021855/is-there-a-way-to-force-overlap-of-two-circles)

Comment: That worked - Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to force overlap of two circles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021855/is-there-a-way-to-force-overlap-of-two-circles)